# System.FormatException DateTime en Razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, razor

mi consulta es que traigo un datos para rellenar un formulario de editar y me sale error de formato
Aqui pongo la definicion del modelo

```
  [Display(Name ="Fecha Apertura"),Required,DataType(DataType.Date),DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:yyyy:MM:dd",ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
    public DateTime fechaApertura { get; set; }
```

Adjunto el controlador, aqui mando a llamar a la base de datos buscado los datos respecto a su id , ahora dato de la fecha lo pongo en DateTime

```
    public ActionResult  Editar(int id)
    {
        SucursalCLS sucursalCLS = new SucursalCLS();    
        using (var bd = new BDPasajeEntities())
        {
            Sucursal oSucusal = bd.Sucursal.Where(p=>p.IIDSUCURSAL== id).FirstOrDefault();
            sucursalCLS.nombre = oSucusal.NOMBRE;
            sucursalCLS.direccion = oSucusal.DIRECCION;
            sucursalCLS.telefono = oSucusal.TELEFONO;
            sucursalCLS.email = oSucusal.EMAIL;
            sucursalCLS.fechaApertura = (DateTime)oSucusal.FECHAAPERTURA;
        }
        return View(sucursalCLS);
    }
```

pero el problema es cuando lo mando a la vista del modelo, me sale error de formato , adjunto la linea donde me sale el error

```
 @Html.LabelFor(p => p.fechaApertura)
            @Html.EditorFor(p => p.fechaApertura, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

p es un helper.

cuando ejecuto el index , pongo el editar , me trae el objeto para poder editar y no alcanza a desplegar el form , me sale el siguiente error

System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.

no he podido arreglarlo, necesito ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me di cuenta de  mi error, esta en el  las referencias de los atributos de la clase , puse

```
DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:yyyy:MM:dd",ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
```

y el error esta en el formato del dataformatstring , es "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"

debí poner guiones y cerrar la llave